# express js routes: displaying a user input in an ejs page

Tags: express, input, routes, ejs

How can I display the result of an input search with express js?

I have defined 2 routes:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.render('index',{
title: "Bilingual Dictionary"
  });
});
```

Then I'm calling this route to display the result of the search:

```
app.post('/word', function(req, res){
var search= req.body.name;
res.render('index', {
title: "Bilingual Dictionary",
search: search
  });

});
```

in my index.ejs, I have:

```
 <h1><%= title %></h1>

 <form id="create-form">
  <input type="text" id="create-input">
  <button>Search</button>
</form>
 <div>

 <%= search %>
 </div>
```

I get the error: search is not defined.

If I change the second route to:

```
app.post('/word', function(req, res){
res.send(search)
});
```

the search result is returned successfully but sent to the console. So I know my ajax call (in a separate scripts.js) works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who have the same problem, I found a solution.
First I had to change the view engine to PUG (but that's not important actually). Then I changed the script that sends the form:

```
$(function(){
$('form').submit(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
 var parameters = { search: $('#searchbox').val() };
   $.get( '/searching',parameters, function(data) {
     console.log(data);
   $('#results').html(data);
   });
  });
  });
```

In order for the input data to show up, I added the last line:
      $('#results').html(data);

Then in app.js I modified the route as follows:

```
app.get('/searching', function(req, res){
var val = req.query.search;
res.send(val);
```

Now when I go to port 3000 and enter a word, it gets displayed on the same page.